# What does the "X" mean in the XMR ticker symbol?

Tags: history

Why was an "X" chosen to be used in the XMR ticker symbol?

"M" and "R" are both contained in the work Monero. What is the meaning of the "X" in the Monero ticker symbol?

Comment: "[Research says that shows with "X" in the name get higher ratings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gT-Vf_x4Dc4)" :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many exchanges prefer a 3 letter ticker symbol. The X is the result of an [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#X_currencies) standard common for commodities and currencies that are not specific to a certain country. [Bitcoin commonly uses XBT](http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-gaining-market-based-legitimacy-xbt/) instead of BTC for the same reason

Answer (score 7):

XMR in an [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) curency code. This standard allocates codes starting with a "X" to "supranational" currencies, of which Monero is one. Other such currencies, or currency-like entities, include XAU (gold, AU being from the Latin Aurum), and XAG for silver.

The choice of XMR (to replace MRO) is designed to make it easier for the existing financial system to work with Monero. Or at least to avoid placing an unnecessary hurdle.