# Where can I find charts of Monero's price to dollar?

Tags: fiat

I'm unable to find them using Google, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try Poloniex website here, which gives usd/xmr chart:

https://poloniex.com/exchange#usdt_xmr

Comment: I think Poloniex is the better option (CoinGeck only 90 days history as far as I can see), just a pity they don't have a 1 year button …

Answer (score 2):

I use CoinGecko : https://www.coingecko.com/en/price_charts/monero/usd

For searches related to price, result are often better if you use "[XMR](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1163/24)" rather than "Monero".

Answer (score 1):

TradingView has very nice charts.

This is the chart for Kraken.com which just enabled XMR trading:

- https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=KRAKEN:XMREUR **
- https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=KRAKEN:XMRUSD

**Note: Kraken specializes in EUR trading, so that chart will be more active.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice simple overview of all cryptos coinmarketcap.com